# Compute fundamental group of $(\mathbb R^n-D^n)\cup\{\infty\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider $X$ as the one-point compatification of $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $X=\mathbb R^n\cup\{\infty\}$ (for $n>2$).

> Let $D^n$ be a closed disk in $\mathbb R^n$. I am trying to convince myself that
> $$\pi_1\big((\mathbb R^n-D^n)\cup\{\infty\}\big)$$
> is trivial

Without the compactification point $\infty$ it is clear that $\pi_1(\mathbb R^n-D^n)$ is trivial, since $\mathbb R^n-D^n$ is a deformation retraction onto any $n$-sphere of radious greather than 1.

Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by ""is the fundamental group.""

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to visualize this as $S^n-D^n$, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^n-\{p\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\{\infty\}$ is a deformation retract of $X:=\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}\backslash D^n$ via

$$[0,1]\times X\to X$$
$$(t,v)\mapsto \begin{cases}
\big(1+\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}t)\big)\cdot v &\text{if }v\neq\infty\text{ and }t\neq 1 \\
\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I leave as an exercise that this function is continuous.

Thus $X$ is contractible.